# order of quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> In $\mathbb{Z}\left [ x \right ]$, let $I = \left \{ f\left ( x \right ) \in \mathbb{Z}\left [ x \right ]: f\left ( 0 \right ) \text{ is an even integer} \right \}$

In fact, $I=\left \langle x,2 \right \rangle$

How do I show that the order of $\mathbb{Z}\left [ x \right ]/I$ is 2?

Comment: It follows from the sum $(I,J)$ of ideals that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,2) = (\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x))/(2) = \mathbb{Z}/(2)$

Comment: Jeez, how often do we have to go through this?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Consider the ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z$ given by $f(x) \mapsto f(0) \bmod 2$.

Equivalently, prove that $f(x) \equiv (f(0) \bmod 2) \bmod I$.

Comment: Is there any other way beside constructing a map?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the quotient by an ideal is the number of cosets the ideal has in the full ring, or equivalently, the number of equivalence classes modulo that ideal. Thinking in terms of cosets, we have that $1+I$ is the set of all polynomials $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $f(0)$ odd. Since $f(0)$ must be odd or even, there can be no more cosets.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $\mathbb Z[x]/I \cong \overline {\mathbb Z}[x] /(x) $, which obviously has order $2$ (where $\overline {\mathbb Z} = \mathbb Z/2$) - via the homomorphism of $\mathbb Z[x]$ to $\overline {\mathbb Z}[x]/(x)$, $a \mapsto a + (2)$, $a \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \mapsto x$.